# Assigning a button width value using Razor

Tags: asp.net, button, razor, width

How do I assign a width to a button using Razor. I have this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGoTo" runat="server" Text="<%= ButtonText %>" class="button" Width="<% (int)ButtonWidth %>px" />
```

But naturally it does not work.

Is there a way to Set the button width using Razor?

Comment: Is this **Razor**? It looks like _plain_ ASP.NET WebForms! So answer is: yes, it's possible with Razor. No, you can't use server side tags inside a runat=server control with ASP.NET (but you can do it from code, normal attributes (style=...) or better CSS.

Comment: Razor (which, by the way, isn't what you're using in this code) is a syntax for server-side code.  HTML element width is a styling concern, client-side.  You should style your elements' widths with CSS, not with server-side code.

Comment: Ah yes - shouldn't post late at night. Although being marked down is harsh. Merry christmas to whoever did that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Razor but anyway...

In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer Window go in the Content-Folder open Site.css - at the end of the file add:

```
.button {
    width: 180px;
}
```

for better results with responsive site you can also use width: 27em; or width: 27rem; (as rem relatively new leave width: 180px; in the line before as fallback)